# How to accept 5 numbers and print there sum using just one variable in the entire program using C language?

Tags: c, input, io, output

I have come across this question in a programming contest, but couldn't find the answer can anyone please help me with this???
input << 5 numbers
output << Their sum

constraints << Only one variable can be used in the entire program(and no the input cant be given from the command prompt)
Thanks in advance!!!

And yeah the contest is over

Comment: Can the variable be an array? ;)

Comment: If it's a contest, why would you (or should you) get help from others on a solution?  The entire point is to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't think there's a solution.

Comment: On SO , you will get help on the technical issues you face , no one will do your outsourced work

Comment: The solution is simple as hell. Just use an array.

Comment: @Randy Howard - No well the contest is over but couldn't get the solutions from the host!!!

Comment: My first thought was a struct ... but an array is also good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, with an array of size 2:

```
main( ) {
  int a[ 2 ];
  a[ 0 ] = 0;
  scanf( "%d", a+1 ); a[ 0 ] += a[ 1 ];
  scanf( "%d", a+1 ); a[ 0 ] += a[ 1 ];
  scanf( "%d", a+1 ); a[ 0 ] += a[ 1 ];
  scanf( "%d", a+1 ); a[ 0 ] += a[ 1 ];
  scanf( "%d", a+1 ); a[ 0 ] += a[ 1 ];
  printf( "%d\n", a[ 0 ] );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess this can be an answer as there was no specific constraint that there cannot be more than one memory location allocated.Hence the Answer! Thanks Rondogiannis Aristophane!

Comment: @SabirAhmed Any time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
    int s[3] = {0};
    while((*s)++<5) {
        printf("Enter number n%d: ",*s);
        scanf("%d",s+1);
        *(s+2) += *(s+1);
    }
    printf("The sum is %d\n",*(s+2));
}
```

Comment: Well im not so sure about this but I guess this is the closest to an answer I can get. Thanks Mohamed KALLEL!!!

Comment: Your are welcome, salem

Comment: @SabirAhmed you can avoid the use of memory allocation in the code I give. answer updated. You have to replece only `int *s = calloc(3, sizeof(int));` with `int s[3] = {0};`

Comment: thanks I got the concept!!!